# Is this a reasonable benchmark

Tags: python

I'm reviewing some code and came across a usage of `dict` that could easily be done with `tuple` -- under my general assumption that `tuple` is fast, I used the `timeit` module to find out. I don't know very much about the internals of Python, so would like to know if what follows is a reasonable benchmark.

```
import timeit


setup_tuples = '''
mapping = (
    ('a', ('b', 'c')),
    ('d', ('e', 'f')),
    ('g', ('h', 'i')),
)
'''

script_tuples = '''
for key, (db_access_fn_name, post_db_fn) in mapping:
    pass
'''

setup_dict = '''
mapping = {
    'a': ('b', 'c'),
    'd': ('e', 'f'),
    'g': ('h', 'i'),
}
'''

script_dict = '''
for key, (db_access_fn_name, post_db_fn) in mapping.items():
    pass
'''

print('tuples')
print(timeit.timeit(script_tuples, setup_tuples))

print('a dict')
print(timeit.timeit(script_dict, setup_dict))
```

Comment: With 3 keys? It is going to become interesting with maybe 3,000 or even 3,000,000.

Comment: Python won't skip your loops just because the body does nothing; that kind of optimization would possibly have visible side-effects, due to the object being iterated being left in a different state.  The syntax of the language DOES require at least one statement in the body of the loop, but that's normally `pass` if you have nothing to do.

Comment: >3 keys?
@KlausD.

The use I have requires three keys.

Comment: In that case (where the data represents your real-world uses well, including in terms of size) the overhead from a dict may well be excessive, and the benchmark a reasonable one. A dict would become competitive if you needed constant-time key lookups as sizes increase, but if they won't increase...

Comment: That said, I would suggest keeping in mind that sometimes readability is more important than performance: Often, programmer-hours are more expensive than machine hours, particularly if this code isn't *actually* being run often enough to make these timings relevant.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, my thought was that there isn't any readability deficit to the `tuple` version. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: My argument (wrt. readability) is that anything that is in dict form is obviously key/value pairs, and obviously in a form where order is unimportant. Anything in tuple form, by contrast, will often (by convention) be in a positionally-dependent format; the type is thus meaningful not just to the interpreter but also provides hints to the reader. Of course, if declaration and use are as close to each other as here, the distinction may be moot.